# Filling Array with Custom Class - retrieving values

Tags: iphone, arrays, nsobject

I have the following code

```
NSMutableArray *leeTemp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
Player* playerLee = [[Player alloc] init];
playerLee.name = [array objectAtIndex:1];
[leeTemp addObject:playerLee];
[playerLee release];
```

And this generates an array of Players (I think)!  When I do the following it shows the addresses of the Players.

```
NSLog(@"%@",leeTemp);
```

What I am struggling with is retreiving say array[0].name, this is a string value.
I'm sure this is very simple but am struggling to visualise this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[leeTemp objectAtIndex:0] name]);
```

Or if you want to loop through an array you can use for..in iteration:

```
for (Player *player in leeTemp) {
  NSLog(@"%@", [player name]);
}
```